# Doesn't the symmetrical function of texture paint work properly if there is an open face?

Tags: texturing

[image]

If the object is open, as in the attached image, it affects the back face when the symmetry function is used.

If I don't use symmetry, it doesn't affect the back face even if it's open

[image]

Any options or solutions related to this?

Comment: Hello maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/